# How to run a script as a different user while staying in current session

Tags: powershell

In my current environment I have a local admin and domain account. I have created a powershell script which runs well when logged into my domain admin account. However, I wish to adapt the script to prompt the user for credentials and then run the script if they have permission.

The current script imports AD and presents the user with a menu. I would like to prompt the user for credentials then present them with the menu if correct.

I have tried adding:

```
start-process powershell.exe -argument C:\Users\Auser\Documents\User Leaver script test.ps1 -credential ""
```

I know this is not the correct method to verify then run the script and other parameters are needed.

An excerpt from the script is contained in the following:

```
$Programstop="No" #Used to Loop 

Do 
{

  PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""C:\Users\Auser\Documents\User Leaver script test.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"; #This line runs script as admin automatically, change file path to point at your script. 

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
set-location ad:"dc=fakepleace,dc=local"



Write-Host "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Credentials = Get-Credentials

Start-Process powershell.exe -argument C:\Users\Auser\Documents\User Leaver script test.ps1 -credential $Credentials -Verb RunAs
```